# Ubuntu 'Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.'

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, mod-security

I am using Google Cloud Platform to test out ModSecurity and I am using a tutorial to launch it. However, I need to restart Apache every once in a while. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I write `sudo systemctl restart apache2`, but an error comes back and it says `Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found`. What should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you install apache2 first ?

```sh
sudo apt install apache2
```

Answer (score 4):

### For those who run into the same issue using Debian

I did have apache2 installed and running as was confirmed by `apache2.service | loaded active running`.

[image]

I still tried to install it.

[image]

I did also get the same error `Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found`

[image]

### How I got apache2 to restart

Using: Debian (9.13)

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or by typing

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl start
```

Comment: Looks like you simply misspelled `apache` as `apatche2` when you tried to restart using `service`.